# JScript confirm infinite loop?

Tags: javascript

```
var setOfCats = {}; //an object
while (r = true) //testing to see if r is true
{
  var i = 0;
  setOfCats.i = prompt ("What's your cat's name?", ""); //index object elements
  alert ("Congratulations! Your cat has been added to the directory.");
  var r = confirm ("Would you like to add another cat?"); //if r is true, then the loop should continue. if false, the loop should end.
  i++
}
```

However, the loop does not end. I've been pondering this problem, with futile attempts, for the last 30 minutes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Your comment is incorrect.

`r = true` doesn't *test* whether `r` is `true`; it *assigns* `r` to become `true`.

You need to *compare* the variable using the `===` operator.

Or you can just write `while(r)`, since `r` itself is already true.

Comment: It **does test** whether `r` is `true` (truthy, here)...the result of the assignment (which happens to be `true` here) is tested. But the whole point of it is ruined because it's **also** setting `r` as `true` at that time, every iteration

Answer (score 3):

```
while (r = true)
```

You're setting `r` to `true` each loop iteration.  You want `while (r == true)`, or just `while (r)`.

Comment: Now the script doesn't run.

Comment: You probably need to set r to true initially.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, `r` and `setOfCats` should be set outside the `while` declaration:

```
var setOfCats = [];
var r = true;

while (r) {
    setOfCats.push( prompt ("What's your cat's name?", "") );
    alert ("Congratulations! Your cat has been added to the directory.");
    r = confirm ("Would you like to add another cat?");
}
```

Comment: Variables are hoisted to the top of the scope, so I don't see how this matters. And `r` is **not** defined in the `while` declaration, it's set

Comment: Removing the `var` keyword would make `r`a global variable – uh-oh! IMHO the best would be to move the declaration outside the loop.

Comment: Ian, yes, and I learned something today. Thanks! Changing answer to reflect Ingo's comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-assigning the value of r to true upon each iteration of the while expression.  Therefore, it will always override the value.

You should do the while test with:

```
while(r === true)
```

or more idiomatic:

```
while(r)
```

This should work:

```
var setOfCats = {}; //an object
var r = true;
while(r) //testing to see if r is true
{
    var i = 0;
    setOfCats.i = prompt ("What's your cat's name?", ""); //index object elements
    alert ("Congratulations! Your cat has been added to the directory.");
    r = confirm ("Would you like to add another cat?"); //if r is true, then the loop should continue. if false, the loop should end.
    i++
}
```